# Better practice for HTML5 web app: using getElementByID or storing a reference?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building one of my first web apps using HTML5, specifically targeting iPhones.

Since I'm pretty new to this, I'm trying to develop some good coding habits, follow best practices, optimize performance, and minimize the load on the resource-constrained iPhone.

One of the things I need to do frequently... I have numerous divs (each of which has a unique id) that I'm frequently updating (e.g., with innerHTML), or modifying (e.g., style attributes with webkit transitions and transforms).

In general - am I better off using getElementByID each time I need a handle to a div, or should I store references to each div I access in "global" variables at the start?

(I use "global" in quotes because I've really just got one truly **global** variable - it's an object that stores all my "global" variables as properties).

I assume using getElementByID each time must have some overhead, since the function needs to traverse the DOM to find the div. But, I'm not sure how taxing or efficient this function is.

Using global variables to store handles to each element must consume some memory, but I don't know if these references require just a trivial amount of RAM, or more than that.

So - which is better? Or, do both options consume such a trivial amount of resources that I should just worry about which produces more readable, maintainable code?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I always try to save references to things and keep scope in mind when I am working in closures.  It will definitely speed up your javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"In general - am I better off using getElementByID each time I need a handle to a div, or should I store references to each div"*

When you're calling `getElementById`, you're asking it to perform a task. If you don't expect a different result when calling the same method with the same argument, then it would seem to make sense to cache the result.

> *"I assume using getElementByID each time must have some overhead, since the function needs to traverse the DOM to find the div. But, I'm not sure how taxing or efficient this function is."*

In modern browsers especially, it's very fast, but not as fast as looking up a property on your global object.

> *"Using global variables to store handles to each element must consume some memory, but I don't know if these references require just a trivial amount of RAM, or more than that."*

Trivial. It's just a pointer to an object that already exists. If you remove the element from the DOM with no intention to use it again, then of course you'll want to release your hold on it.

> *"So - which is better? Or, do both options consume such a trivial amount of resources that I should just worry about which produces more readable, maintainable code?"*

Depends entirely on the situation. If you're only fetching it a couple times, then you may not find it worthwhile to add to your global object. The more you need to fetch the same element, the more sense it makes to cache it.

---

[Here's a jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-getelementbyid) to compare. Of course size of your DOM as well as length of variable scope traversal and the number/depth of properties in your global object will play some role.

Comment: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-getelementbyid/2) memoizing getelementbyid manually is bad

Comment: @mattstuehler I murder devs every day for passing element IDs around. References are definitely the way to go. And if you're clever about your use of closures, you can avoid polluting the global namespace. Remember: DOM access is expensive. When adding several elements to the page, do it "commit" style and wait until all the nodes have been generated before attaching them. When getting something out of the document, save the result if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

Using a local variable or even an object property is much faster than getElementById().  However, both are so fast that their performance is generally irrelevant compared to any other operation you might do once you have the element.  Event setting a single property on the element is orders of magnitude slower than retrieving it by either method.

So the main reason to cache an element is to avoid the rather long-winded document.getElementById(... syntax, or to avoid having element ID strings scattered all over your code.